# Appengine Entity Design Advice

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a dilemma on how to implement this requierement:
Let's say I have the following Contact classes

- Student,
- Tutor,
- AdminStaff.

I am not sure what is the best way to structure it in DataStore:

- shall I have one Contact entity which will contain shared fields and also corresponding extra fields for given type
- or shall I have three separate entities

first approach allows me to search through all my contacts, and the second is to avoid extra filtering when I just need contacts of certain kind.

However I have one more requirement which I am not sure how to accommodate with any of these approaches. What if I have contact with multiple personalities e.g. Tutor and AdminStaff.  This suggests I have a separate Contact entity and link to its various personalities. So for the above example I would have data about that person kept in three entities Contact,Tutor,AdminStaff.

I would appreciate for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your concern about searching over all your contacts - even if you have 3 different entity types, I think you could still create an index that would allow you to search over all contacts.

I don't know how many attributes there are that are unique to the different contact roles, but I'd be worried about creating a single mega-class/entity that encompassed them all - it could be a very big and messy class.

And, as you have indicated, your final requirement does make things more complicated.  It suggests that perhaps you should have a single contact class/entity for all roles, and then create class(es) for the 3 roles that can be @embed'ed into to the contact entity.

Comment: It doesn't need to be all encompassing, with AppEngine we can do polymorphic entities due to schemaless nature of the datastore. As for embedding the problem with them that these fields will be unindexed.

Comment: @husayt The entities' can be polymorphic in the datastore, but my concern was of the Java class that corresponds to the entity.

Comment: @husayt - objectify can embed classes so that they are indexed: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Embedded_Classes